# How to count number of spaces in given string

Tags: python

```
a = input("Enter the string paragraph:")
count = 0
for c in a:
    if c == " ":
        count += 1
        print("Number of spaces in a string:", count)
```

How do I count the number of spaces?

Comment: My question is simple, User has entered the set of character or string , Eg:  I a m in the cof fe e sh op.  So I wanted to count number of space in the full user input. So totally there are 8 space. and I also want to print at which all position the space is ...

Answer (score 33):

```
>>> a=input("Enter the value ")
Enter the value "My Testing String"
>>> a.count(' ')
2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer,

Comment: Sorry I missed to mention that I wanted it more dynamic,    Like my user input is " S t r i ng A b".  So the total count is = 6 but I want something like ' Space is at position = 2,4,6,8,11 etc ..'

Comment: Can you please provide your input method?

Comment: input method is str, As I am executing in on windows 7 using IDLE 3.5

Comment: `print [n for n in xrange(len(a)) if a.find(' ', n) == n]`

Comment: print(n for n in xrange(len(a))if a.find(' ',n)==n)
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined                                                                                               This is the error i am getting

Comment: Use range instead of xrange.

Comment: `range` in Python 3.x is `xrange` from Python 2.x. It was in fact Python 2.x's range that was removed.

Comment: OPS!!!!  this time   "<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000035836D0>"                                                                                 it is showing this , but it is not an error I think it is indicating some value

Comment: I am using 2.7.6  and I am not getting that